# ListBox items changes based on condition

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am getting data in JSON and storing in List by

```
List<Product> rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(e.Result);
```

and after that, I am displaying data in ListBox by

```
   productlist.ItemsSource = rootObject;
```

My xaml file:-

```
 <ListBox Height="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,91,0,0" Name="productlist" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" 
                 SelectionChanged="productlistselectionchanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="132">
                        <!--    <Image Source="{Binding Path=http://callme4.com/images/classifieds/ad_images/IMG_20130728_132750.jpg}" Height="73" Width="73" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,8,0"/> -->
                        <StackPanel Width="370">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="#FFC8AB14" FontSize="28" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding city}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                            <TextBlock Name="price" Text="{Binding price}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My listbox working fine.

But Now i have a condition in **price textblock** such as example:-

```
if(price > 2000)
 textblock values should be purchased.
else
 textblock values should be "not purchased"
```

But i am confused about it, how can i do ?

please expert check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a value converter. see some samples [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/talking-about-converters-in-wp7--coding4fun-toolkit-converters-in-depth)

Create a converter class

```
public class PurchaseStatusConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const double comparePrice = 2000;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double price;

        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out price))
        {
            return price > comparePrice ? "Purchased" : "Not Purchased";
        }

        return "-";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your app.xaml, define the converter, take care of namespaces, re-sharper should handle this for you if you have it installed.

```
   <Application.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:PurchaseStatusConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:namespacetoyourtype" x:Key="PurchaseStatusConverter" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources >
```

finally, in your textbox, reference the converter.

```
<TextBlock Name="price" Text="{Binding price, Converter={StaticResource PurchaseStatusConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
```

Comment: if i want to hide a textblock based on a condition and if condition is true then two new textblock should be display other wise one.

Comment: You would still need to use a value converter and set the Visibility to either Visible or Colapsed. You can then bind the result against the controls visibility attribute. See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a collapsed visibility when the price is less than or equal to the comparison price. 
/// </summary>
public class PriceToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const double comparePrice = 2000;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double price;

        if (double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out price))
        {
            return price > comparePrice ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in your app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources >
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:PurchaseStatusConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:namespacetoyourtype" x:Key="PurchaseStatusConverter" />
        <converter:PriceToVisibilityConverter xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:namespacetoyourtype" x:Key="PriceToVisibilityConverter" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources >
```

In your xaml

```
<TextBlock Name="price" Vis Text="Some text" Visibility="{Binding Price, Converter={StaticResource PriceToVisibilityConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" />
```